# How to read data from "com.sec.android.gallary3d" folder?

Tags: android, directory, internals

I am working on app that is required to read the recover to deleted data. I search a lot but could not find a single solution.
Then I got to know that there is a director "com.sec.android.gallery3d" where all images are saved in small thumbnails. 
My question can I read images?
I checked this sample code. But its only reading those directories which is public like DCIM, notification,Down etc

````
File file=Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);

public ArrayList<File> listf(File xfile, ArrayList<File> files) {


    // get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = xfile.listFiles();
    for (File file : fList) {
        if (file.isFile()) {
            files.add(file);
        } else if (file.isDirectory()) {
            listf(file, files);
        }
    }
    return files;
}```
````

Comment: Well where did you find that directory? Full path please. Also tell the value of first file. file.getAbsolutePath().

Comment: Which Android version?

Comment: If you know the path to that directory you can immediately list its content.

Comment: it present in internal storage/

Comment: sir its in android/data/com,sec.android.gallery3d.

Comment: That is not a full path. And i asked the value of another path too.

Comment: sir  I want to get the data from this path. That was my question actually. Which path you asking please?